# Problem with transmission of a material that uses principled shader

Tags: rendering, materials, eevee-render-engine

[image: screenshot of material not acting as expected]

I'm having an issue with transmission in the principled shader. As you can see my material's base colour is blue, but when I add transmission to it goes dark?

EDIT: Also just realized that I left transmission roughness on 1, I was just trying to see if anything's gonna change with that, but no. It remained the same. So on transmission roughness any value from 0 to 1... no difference at all.

EDIT2: Using Eevee

Comment: are you using eevee are cycles?

Comment: I'm using eevee

Comment: i have the same problem,  transmission doesn't seem to work with eevee. (I know for a fact that it can, but I can't figure it out.  What's annoying is that i thought glass would be easier in eevee because it wouldn't be realistic, so I could make a windshield that didn't distort the characters looking through it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Material Tab. Scroll down to "Settings" and Check "Screen Space Refraction"

[image]

You also need to enable "Refraction" in the "Screen Space Reflections" panel of the render properties. Render engine must be set to Eevee beforehand.

[image]

Also make sure the roughness value is not too high, above 0.5 it will gradually prevent refraction.